# Intuitive proof of Lyapunov's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I have recently come across Lyapunov's stability theorem, which states:

> Let $0$ be an equilibrium of a differential autonomous system $X'=f(X)$ where $f$ is smooth.
>
> Suppose $V$ is a Lyapunov function of the system in some neighborhood of $0$; that is, $V(X(t))$ is non-increasing on $t$ for every solution $X$ of the system, and furthermore suppose that $V$ is definite positive.
>
> Then $0$ is a stable equilibrium.

Sadly, all the proofs I have seen feel rather obscure to me.

Do you know of any good, intuitive proof of the theorem? (or would you be so kind to outline one yourself?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall $0$ is a stable equilibrium if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|X(t_1)\| < \epsilon$ for all $X$ satisfying $\|X(t_0)\| < \delta$ for some $t_0<t_1.$

Given $\epsilon>0,$ by continuity of $V$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $V(x)<\min_{\|x'\|=\epsilon}V(x')$ for $\|x\|<\delta.$ Assume $\|X(t_0)\|<\delta.$ For any $t>t_0$ we have $V(X(t))\leq V(X(t_0))$ and hence $\|X(t)\|\neq\epsilon.$ By the intermediate value theorem, $\|X(t)\|$ will never exceed $\epsilon$ with $t\geq t_0.$

Comment: I would really like to see a proof that avoids pesky epsilon delta notation, but in the absence of one I will undoubtedly award the bounty to this answer